# Ruby on Rails post path turns into get path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby on Rails 5 for a personal project and I can't seem to get my link routes to the correct controller action and client action.

```
<div class="admin-users index">
    <h2>Admin Users</h2>
    <%= image_tag('plus_sign.png', :size => '11x11', :alt => '+') %>
    <%= link_to("Add New Admin User", new_admin_user_path, :class => 'action new') %>
    <table class="listing" summary="Admin user list">
        <tr class="header">
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <% @admin_users.each do |admin_user| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= admin_user.username %></td>
            <td><%= admin_user.name %></td>
            <td><%= mail_to(admin_user.email) %></td>
            <td class="actions">
                <%= link_to("Edit", edit_admin_user_path(admin_user), :class => 'action edit') %>
                <%= link_to("Delete", delete_admin_user_path(admin_user), :class => 'action delete') %>
                <%= link_to("Follow User", followings_path(:followed_id => admin_user), :method => :post)%>


            </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have a link action to make post requests to create a binding between two users.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :followings, :except => [:show, :update, :delete, :new] do
  end
```

I used resources routing to make things simpler for me, unfortunately when I click on Follow User, my post request turns into a get request and I can't add any user to my following list.

```
http://localhost:3000/followings?followed_id=5
```

When I click to the Follow User button, it leads me to the url above, which is fine, but then after looking at the console I see it's a GET request.

```
Started GET "/followings?followed_id=5" for ::1 at 2016-12-24 18:16:26 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by FollowingsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"followed_id"=>"5"}
  AdminUser Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  `admin_users`.* FROM `admin_users` WHERE `admin_users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendering followings/index.html.erb within layouts/admin
  Following Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `followings`.* FROM `followings` WHERE `followings`.`admin_user_id` = 1
  AdminUser Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `admin_users`.* FROM `admin_users` WHERE `admin_users`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  Rendered followings/index.html.erb within layouts/admin (64.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 542ms (Views: 448.4ms | ActiveRecord: 10.0ms)
```

Here's the following controller:

```
class FollowingsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin'
  def index
    admin_user = AdminUser.find(session[:user_id])
    @user = admin_user
  end

  def create
      current_user = AdminUser.find(session[:user_id])
      @following = current_user.following.build(:followed_id => params[:followed_id])
      if @following.save
        flash[:notice] = "Added user."
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Cannot add user."
        redirect_to(admin_users_path)
      end
  end

  def destroy
      current_user = AdminUser.find(session[:user_id])
      @following = current_user.followings.find(params[:id])
      @following.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Removed user."
      redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Can't figure why it's doing this.

Comment: Does the generated html have a `data-method=post` in the link?

Comment: Yes, it does have it.

Comment: Could u show `following` controller?

Comment: What is the output of 'rake routes'? Iirc post routes use plural? So 'new_admin_users_path'

Comment: Did not you remove the jquery lines from your assets/application.js by any chance? jquery is needed for those data-method="post" link to work. you should also check if you see any JS error in the browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I would imagine it has something to do with the routes you have set up for "Followings".  Followings is not a plural for following so doesn't adhere to the Rails naming conventions, so it can't generate the routes correctly. I would switch that resource to "Followers" (since followers is a plural of follower) or set up your own custom routes instead of using the resources method. You could do something like:

```
post 'follow_user/:followed_id' => 'followings#create', as: :follow_user
get 'followings' => 'followings#index', as: :followings
```

Then your follow user link would be:

```
<%= link_to("Follow User", follow_user_path(followed_id: admin_user), method: :post) %>
```

I also would suggest using strong parameters in your controller when updating or creating records. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html